# Symfony fixtures - is it possible to 'dummy' create dates?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, fixtures

I have fixtures that I am trying to create that are dependent on other entities createDT stamps. However, I'm unable to 'spoof' these as I use `@prepersist` to populate the createDT fields in my entities. I have quite a lot of entities that are involved and I'm wondering if there is any way I can temporarily freeze/override this `@prepersist` just for loading my fixtures?

My entities all have:

```
/**
 * Set createDT
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function setCreateDT()
{
    $this->createDT = new \DateTime();
    return $this;
}
```

...and I am trying to conditionally specify fixtures' values in the below kind-of way, comparing against the `createDT` of another entity:

```
class LoadTransactionData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface {
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager) {
        for ($month=1; $month <= 120; $month++) {
            $transaction = new Transaction();
            $date = new \DateTime();

            if($date->setDate(2000 + floor($month/12),$month % 12,1) < $this->getReference('AC_1')->getCreateDT()) {
                // ...get references etc and do stuff here....
            } else {
                // ...get references etc and do other stuff here...
            }
            $manager->persist($transaction);
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }
```

**UPDATE:** The above would be the best, but if not possible, it could perhaps be sufficient if there is a way to delay the persisting of some records? That way, I can at least make a timestamp difference of a second or two for comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be assign the date in *constructor* method:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->createDT = new \DateTime();
}
```

Thus, when your fixtures are loaded this date is overridden.

Comment: Thanks - I was hopeful as seemed like a good idea but unfortunately no luck! The `PrePersist` is still catching it and populating the record with the current DT stamp

Comment: That works thank you :-) A shame to have to disconnect all the `PrePersists` but at least it works!